# How to differentiate between Macbook and iPad using PHP?

Tags: php, macos, ipad, user-agent

The user agent for both these devices seems to be the exact same! How can I differentiate between them using PHP?

Currently I am accessing

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]
```

to check the user agent.

Comment: https://github.com/hisorange/browser-detect